# How do I transfer my wallet to a new one?

Tags: wallet

wallet, g Bitcoin Wallet (official) for Android and I want to transfer my wallet from there, to Electrum on my desktop. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you try making an address in Electrum, then transferring all of your bitcoins to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of transferring the wallet, just transfer the bitcoins - i.e. on Android: Send the entire amount to your electrum-address.

Comment: But isn't there a fee when doing that?

Comment: @Propeller usually fee is 0.0005 BTD, ~0.08 USD at current exchange rate... likely you can afford it.